# Adding an animation element in the Radial Gauge (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have already created a page that obtains values and depicts the same using a radial gauge with a needle. Inside my radial gauge, I have markings and highlights, that is from 0 - 60 the highlights colour is green, and for markings 60-100, the strokes will be over highlights of red colour. Both these colours are given an opacity of 0.2 value (20% of original colour). Now, I need to add animation such that, when my needle moves, I need my highlights colour to change to a darker shade (opacity = 1, meaning full exact colour) in an animated manner.

I have used gauge.min.js for my radial gauge.
Below is the code. Please suggest me what can be done.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="gauge.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Gauge Test</title>
     <style>

        .gauge-container {
        display: inline-block;
            margin: 2px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 9px;
            text-align: center;
       // width: 25%; /* Adjust the width based on your preference */
    
        }

        .gauge-title {
            margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        }

.gauge-container:first-child {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        function GetTagValues() {
            // Send the request
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "link1.shtm", dataType: "json", success: TagValuesReceived, 
        error: TagValuesError, timeout: 10000
            });

            // Update value in webpage
        }

        function TagValuesReceived(json) {
            data1.value = json.X_DATA;

            setTimeout("GetTagValues()", 1000);
        }

        function TagValuesError() {

        }

        GetTagValues();
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="gauge-container">
        <a type="button" href="http://10.121.62.74/usr/LUB_PR.shtm" target="data1"><canvas id="gauge1"></canvas></a>
    <h2 class="gauge-title">X_Current</h2>
        <div id="gauge1"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

   <script>
        var data1 = new RadialGauge({
            renderTo: 'gauge1',
            width: 190,
            height: 190,
            units: 'A',
            title: false,
            value: 0,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            majorTicks: ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'],
            minorTicks: 2,
            strokeTicks: true,
            highlights: [
                { "from": 0, "to": 60, "color": "rgba(0,255,0,.15)" },
                { "from": 60, "to": 100, "color": "rgba(255,30,0,.25)" }
             ],
            animationDuration: 1500,
            animationRule: "linear",
        }).draw();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using different methods, but I was only able to achieve a bar like structure outside my radial gauge along its edges that gets filled. But I want this same bar like thing inside my gauge, with highlights also initially, and also markings over it. (Bar in the sense, a radial (curved) structure outside and along the curve of my gauge)

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what code is being produced? In this case, what element those colors are being used on? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help put this info into your question.